# fitting an exponential curve with squared exponent through three points

Tags: calculus, statistics, graphing-functions, least-squares

I apologize if the format is horrible! I am not sure how to do this.

\begin{center}
I am using least squares regression to fit an exponential to my data. Thus, I need to find a good guess for initial parameters. The model function for this data is 
\end{center}

\begin{equation}
y\ =\ ae^{bK^{2}} +c
\end{equation}
\begin{center}

where $\displaystyle K\ =b^{-1} \ \sqrt{2( x+3/2)}$ and $\displaystyle b\ =\ 0.15$
\end{center}
Here is the method that i have done, however it does not result in a very good fit.

\begin{gather*}
y_{1} \ =\ ae^{bK^{2}_{1}} +c\\
y_{2} \ =\ ae^{bK^{2}_{2}} +c\\
y_{3} =ae^{bK^{2}_{3}} +c
\end{gather*}
Thus,
\begin{gather*}
y_{1} '\ =\ 2abK_{1} e^{bK^{2}_{1}}\\
y_{2} '\ =\ 2abK_{2} e^{bK^{2}_{2}}
\end{gather*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac{y_{2} '}{y1'} =\frac{K_{2}}{K_{1}} e^{b\left( K^{2}_{2} -K1^{2}\right)}
\end{equation*}
Moreover, note that $\displaystyle y_{2} '\ =\ \frac{dy_{2}}{dK_{2}} =\frac{y_{3} -y_{2}}{K_{3} -K_{2}}$ and similarly, $\displaystyle y_{1} '=\ \frac{y_{2} -y_{1}}{K_{2} -K_{1}}$.

Thus $\displaystyle b$ is equal to

\begin{gather*}
b\ =\ \ln\left(\frac{y_{2} 'K_{1}}{y_{1} 'K_{2}}\right) /\left( K^{2}_{2} -K^{2}_{1}\right)\\
\end{gather*}
Now to find $\displaystyle a$, we will eliminate $\displaystyle c$ by

\begin{gather*}
y_{2} -y_{1} \ =\ a\left( e^{bK^{2}_{2}} -e^{bK^{2}_{1}}\right)\\
y_{3} -y_{2} \ =\ a\left( e^{bK^{2}_{3}} -e^{bK^{2}_{2}}\right)
\end{gather*}
so
\begin{gather*}
a_{1} \ =\ \frac{y_{2} -y_{1}}{e^{bK^{2}_{2}} -e^{bK^{2}_{1}}}\\
a_{2} \ =\ \frac{y_{3} -y_{2}}{e^{bK^{2}_{3}} -e^{bK^{2}_{2}}}
\end{gather*}
and we have $\displaystyle a\ =\frac{a_{1} +a_{2}}{2}$.

Now for $\displaystyle c$ we just plug in all the values into each equation and solve for $\displaystyle c$. i.e

\begin{gather*}
c_{1} \ =\ ae^{bK^{2}_{1}} -y_{1}\\
c_{2} \ =\ ae^{bK^{2}_{2}} -y_{2}\\
c_{3} =ae^{bK^{2}_{3}} -y_{3}
\end{gather*}
so $\displaystyle c\ =\ \frac{c_{1} +c_{2} +c_{3}}{3}$ .

When I plot this fit against the data, the curve only really fits through the first three points. I am not sure what is going on or where the problem is.

DATA:
\begin{gather*}
( 2,2.35448742279577\ \ )\\
( 4,-1.368206934161941)\\
( 6,-3.305390118335089)\\
( 8,-4.482711701457797)\\
( 10,-5.266602875206834)\\
( 12,-5.820768423448095)\\
( 14-6.229391391650249)\\
( 16,-6.540202260195814)\\
( 18-6.782285215077716)\\
( 20-6.974372715890539)
\end{gather*}
[THE ATTEMPT PLOTTED IS HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQoaT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question will probably win the contest of the most muddled wording.

The first step is to simplify it.
$$y=ae^{bK^2}+c\quad;\quad K=b^{-1}\sqrt{2(x+3/2)}$$
$$y=ae^{(2x+3)/b}+c$$
$$y=ae^{3/b}e^{(2/b)x}+c$$
Let $\quad \beta=a e^{3/b}\quad$ ; $\quad\gamma=\frac{2}{b}\quad $ and $\quad\alpha=c$ .

$$\boxed{y=\alpha +\beta e^{\gamma x}}$$
The question becomes very simple : How to fit this function to the given data. That is all the problem if I well understand the original question.

The answer is : Use any available non-linear regression solftware.

Alternatively we will use another method which doesn't require iterative calculus.

The principle is explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . Copy below of the application to the present problem.

[image]

[image]

The notations $a,b,c$ in the referenced paper are not the same as the notations $a,b,c$ in the question of the OP. This is confusing. In order to clarify the relationships are written below, in coming back to the notations of the OP.

[image]

Both equations give the same blue curve on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the equation in a tortured way, but I guess that in the end we can write

$$y=e^{ax+b}+c.$$ (My constant aren't yours.)

For three general points, there is no closed-form formula, the equation is transcendental. But for three equidistant abscissas (as the plot seems to show), there is an option:

$$y_0=e^{ax_0+b}+c,\\y_1=e^{a(x_0+h)+b}+c,\\y_2=e^{a(x_0+2h)+b}+c$$

then,

$$\frac{y_2-y_1}{y_1-y_0}=\frac{e^{2ah}-e^{ah}}{e^{ah}-1}=e^{ah}.$$

From this, draw $a$, and the rest follows.

Comment: will this work even if the exponent term is squared, so y = e^(ax^2 + b) + c?

Comment: @JosephSanders: your exponents are not squared !